# How to Write the File and File Path to table

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package - which within a FOR LOOP CONTAINER I look in a particular location, for a particular file format and import it into a database.

This is working fine - when I have two files the contents of both files are being imported.

So I have a Variable Mapping under my ForLoop which records the fully qualified name. What I want to do is when I import the file is I am also recording the file path of where it has come from.

I'm unsure in my dataflow task where I would put that ? Under the data flow I have my source file and a destination.

I tried to have a sql task after the data flow that updated the field in the database with the variable (via Parameter Mapping), but that set the field to the same value for everything (the last file path found) which is not what I'm after.

Any advice would be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dataflow task, in between your `source` and `destination` add a `Derived Column` transformation.  This will add columns to your dataset with a name and value that you specify.  If you reference variables in which you are storing the file name for your loop container, the name of the file being accessed will be appended to an additional column in your dataset.  Obviously you need to make sure that this column is present in your destination table.

Comment: Thanks for this!! Problem is the File Name is still the same for all the imports even though I have two files?